# WP7 List Box alignment and styling issues

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, windows-phone-7.1

I want to create a `windows phone` screen which will display the some users info in a `listbox` like following

[image]

Right now i am doing this using following code its working fine.

```
   <ListBox>
   <ListBoxItem Height="100">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="Assets/Users/dummyUser2.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="90" Width="90" />
                            <TextBlock Text="John Smith" Style="{StaticResource ProfileNameStyleForTextBlock}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Birthday" Style="{StaticResource EventNameStyleForTextBlock}"   />
                            <TextBlock Text="Today" Style="{StaticResource EventDateStyleForTextBlock}" Foreground="#09aba9" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ListBoxItem>
   ...........
   ......
   </ListBox>
```

What i want to do is, i want to load the items into list box dynamically from code behind and the view should be look like above image.

Is it possible to create a style/control like this and add it to all the lists i'll create in future.

### Edit

### My ListBox

```
<ListBox Name="lstlist" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GuyDataTemplate}" />
```

### DataTemplate

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="GuyDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="Assets/Users/dummyUser2.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="90" Width="90" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource ProfileNameStyleForTextBlock}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Event}" Style="{StaticResource EventNameStyleForTextBlock}"   />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" Style="{StaticResource EventDateStyleForTextBlock}" Foreground="#09aba9" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I created a class as

```
public class Guy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

and wrote the logic in a `buttonclick`

```
 ObservableCollection<Guy> Guys = new ObservableCollection<Guy>();
        Guys.Add(new Guy() { Name = "xyzabc", Event = "event details", Date = "19/25/0258" });
        Guys.Add(new Guy() { Name = "xyzabc", Event = "event details", Date = "19/25/0258" });
        Guys.Add(new Guy() { Name = "xyzabc", Event = "event details", Date = "19/25/0258" });
        Guys.Add(new Guy() { Name = "xyzabc", Event = "event details", Date = "19/25/0258" });

        lstlist.ItemsSource = Guys;
```

After adding this app got **stucked**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define `DataTemplate` for `ListBox` item in resources :

```
           <DataTemplate x:Key="GuyDataTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="Assets/Users/dummyUser2.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="90" Width="90" />
                        <TextBlock Text="John Smith" Style="{StaticResource ProfileNameStyleForTextBlock}" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Birthday" Style="{StaticResource EventNameStyleForTextBlock}"   />
                        <TextBlock Text="Today" Style="{StaticResource EventDateStyleForTextBlock}" Foreground="#09aba9" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
```

and use it from every `ListBox` you want:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Guys} ItemTemplate={StaticResource GuyDataTemplate} />
```

, where `Guys` is `ObservableCollection<>`

add new item:

```
Guys.Add(new Guy() { Name = "Will Snith" });
```

P.S.

`UserControl` is not recommended to use as `ListBox` item

Comment: can you give brief idea what should i write in code behind for `Guys`

Comment: Hi after adding this my app got stucked what to do, in debug also its not working........

Comment: Don't forget to put `DataTemplate` to `Resources`. `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources> </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>`, for example

Comment: Your code is seams to be right. I just tried it and all works. Are any errors appears or something else? What is mean `stucked`?

Comment: i put `DataTemplate` in `Resources` section only

Comment: Stuck means app not working im not able to click the button in the app also

Comment: `Button` is below the empty `ListBox` I guess, so it can't be clicked... Move code from button click event to a constructor

Comment: when i debug its going into this method `Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)`

Comment: Thank you for the idea man im new to wp7, now i have an idea how to do